# How do I configure driver memory when running Spark in local mode via Sparklyr?

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using Sparklyr to run a Spark application in local mode on a virtual machine with 244GB of RAM. In my code I use `spark_read_csv()` to read in ~50MB of csvs from one folder and then ~1.5GB of csvs from a second folder. My issue is that the application throws an error when trying to read in the second folder.

As I understand it, the issue is that the default RAM available to the driver JVM is 512MB - too small for the second folder (in local mode all operations are run within the driver JVM, as described here 
[How to set Apache Spark Executor memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562033/how-to-set-apache-spark-executor-memory). So I need to increase the `spark.driver.memory` parameter to something larger.

The issue is that I cannot set this parameter through the normal methods described in the [sparklyr documentation](http://spark.rstudio.com/deployment.html) (i.e. via `spark_config()`, the `config.yml` file, or the `spark-defaults.conf` file):

> in local mode, by the time you run spark-submit, a JVM has already been launched with the default memory settings, so setting "spark.driver.memory" in your conf won't actually do anything for you. Instead, you need to run spark-submit as follows:

```
bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 2g --class your.class.here app.jar
```

(from [How to set Apache Spark Executor memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562033/how-to-set-apache-spark-executor-memory)).

I thought I could replicate the `bin/spark-submit` command above by adding the `sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` option to the `config.yml`; as stated in the Sparklyr documentation; `sparklyr.shell*` options are command line parameters that get passed to `spark-submit`, i.e. adding `sparklyr.shell.driver-memory: 5G` to the `config.yml` file should be equivalent to running `bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 5G`.

I have now tried all of the above options and none of them change driver memory in the Spark application (which I check by looking at the 'Executors' tab of the Spark UI).

So how can I change driver memory when running Spark in local mode via Sparklyr?

Comment: I'm running sparklyr_0.5.4-9004, spark 2.0.1, & R 3.4.0 on a Windows machine FYI

Comment: Hi jay, I've the same issue as you today. Did you manage to find a solution in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions @Aydin K. Ultimately I was able to configure driver memory by first updating java to 64bit (allows utilisation of >4G of RAM in the JVMs), then using the `sparklyr.shell*` parameters within the `spark_config()` object:

```
config <- spark_config()
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- '30G'
config$`sparklyr.shell.executor-memory` <- '30G'
sc <- spark_connect(master='local', version='2.0.1', config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and no luck with my mavenized java application (local[*]) with adjusting the local memory settings. Tried lot of combinations (spark-env.sh, spark-defaults.conf etc)..

Therefore I did following workaround:

1)  Add desired memory size parameters to:
/opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.driver.memory     4g
spark.executor.memory   2g
```

2) Build a jar (`mvn package` in my case)

3) Submit application from command line via spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --repositories https://mvnrepository.com --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.10 --class com.mypackage.myApp --verbose --master local[*] ./target/com.mypackage.myApp-1.0.jar
```

And voila, no more java "out of memory" space issues :-) Also the spark UI shows now the correct value in the executor tab.

Comment: thank you for the suggested workaround. If I submit the spark application directly using spark-submit then how do I 'connect' sparklyr to spark? Ideally I would be following the workflow described in the sparklyr documentation, i.e. sending sparklyr code to Spark via RStudio.

Comment: To  be honest I've not worked with RStudio and sparklyR, but did you also try the --sparklyr.shell.executor-memory 5G parameter (instead of the driver related one)

Comment: also have a look on this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384336/running-out-of-heap-space-in-sparklyr-but-have-plenty-of-memory